# Set Required Field Validator from .ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am trying to set the enable attribute on a required field validator control from a function in my code behind.  The below code seems to not be working.  What am I missing? I am doing this so I can test my code behind validation and not have to go to all required field validator controls to change the enable property to false etc.

```
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRadTxtTimerName" 
                runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
                ControlToValidate="txtTimerName"
                ErrorMessage="* Email Address is a required field."
                ValidationGroup="submitTimer"
                Enabled=<%# (EnableOrDisableRequiredValidators() == true ? true : false) %>
                Display="Dynamic" >
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


    protected bool EnableOrDisableRequiredValidators()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Where is this RequiredFieldValidator located? For example, GridView, Repeater...

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why don't you set it directly in the code-behind? Setting a variable in the code behind, then the server control to the variable just seems like a difficult way to do it.

Comment: You are correct MikeSmithDev.  I was set on doing it in the .APSX page and not sure why I didn't do it in the code behind.

Comment: I now Believe I was doing it because I was doing data binding in aspx page for a grid edit template, so I wanted to set the enabled property from the start instead of having to do it in the Item_data_bound event etc.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRadTxtTimerName" 
    runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
    ControlToValidate="txtTimerName"
    ErrorMessage="* Email Address is a required field."
    ValidationGroup="submitTimer"
    Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Meanwhile somewhere in code behind:

```
rfvRadTxtTimerName.Enabled = false // true?
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it has to do with data binding and when controls values are initialized.

As an aside, this line (if you found a way to make it work)

```
Enabled=<%# (EnableOrDisableRequiredValidators() == true ? true : false) %>
```

could be cleaned up

```
Enabled=<%# EnableOrDisableRequiredValidators() %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your information.  I didn't think about doing it that way, so I will change my code to this. I guess I was set on doing it in the .APSX page compared to code behind, but your way will work with code behind

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SetEnablePropertyForRequireFieldValidators();

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

            }

        }

        private void SetEnablePropertyForRequireFieldValidators()
        {
            bool enabledOrDisabled = EnableOrDisableRequiredValidators();

            rfvRadTxtTimerName.Enabled = enabledOrDisabled;
        }